# How to filter values extracted from HTML table

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I want to scrape stats and odds from betexplorer, in particular this site https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2019-2020/cska-moscow-fc-tambov/8Ya3mpOC/

```
homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'aodds')]").text
```

I have this return

```
CLOSING ODDS
22.07. 17:48 1.28 +0.01
OPENING ODDS
17.07. 00:07 1.27
```

How could I scrape only the opening odds?

Comment: I still don't find the text `CLOSING ODDS` and `OPENING ODDS` within the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An xpath such as:

```
//tbody[contains(@id,'aodds')]/tr[4]
```

Seems to highlight the relevant row in the DOM:
[image]

From that, you can look to find_elements and print out each child `td`.  (shout if you need support with this)

As an alternative, if you already have the whole text you can just manipulate your string.
Assuming `homeodd` contains the text you post:

```
print (homeodd.split('OPENING ODDS')[-1])
```

That will split around your required text and the `[-1]` takes the last item in the array - i.e. everything after opening odds.

Answer (score 2):

Try more specific XPath to get Opening Odds only:

```
xpath = '//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr'
homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

If you want to ignore *date* and *change* values:

```
xpath = '//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]'
```